# Git ammend not allowed after resolving cherry-pick conflicts

Tags: git

I `cherry-picked` a commit and resolved the conflicts, added them, now when I try to do git amend it fails with below message.

> fatal: You are in the middle of a cherry-pick -- cannot amend.

Why does git gives this message, is there a way to tell it things are fine?

Comment: `git cherry-pick --continue`

Comment: wouldn't that create a new commit?

Comment: @garg10may No, it will finish what you did to the cherry-pick with the conflict. I needs to be committed, not just added. Use `--continue`, it's the same as with rebase when there is conflict. If you want to amend the commit with conflict, just add the files and then do `--continue`, no need for amend.

Comment: It not compulsory to continue, threre's a way around,  I highlighted it in answer.

Comment: if this helps https://stackoverflow.com/a/58425801/4785824

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I  manually removed `.git/CHERRY_PICK_HEAD` now git doesn't know I did a cherry-pick, so amend works like it was a normal commit amend.

`cherry-pick --continue` adds a new commit message and would need to rebase  which is a hassle.

Comment: This works, but it would be better not touch files in .git directory manually. you can actually first cherry-pick --continue to add new commit, then revert the commit by "git reset HEAD~", at this point you are not longer in process of cherry-pick. so you can commit amend.

Answer (score 8):

It seems that you did a `cherry-pick` before, which failed due to conflicts. Thus, git thinks you're still in the middle of the cherry pick, since it expects you to fix conflicts, add conflicted files and run `git cherry-pick --continue`.

Your options here are to run `git cherry-pick --abort` which will abort the cherry pick, i.e. return the conflicted files to their previous state, possible losing changes, or to run `git cherry-pick --continue`, which will continue the cherry pick. When you do not remember when and what you did with the cherry-pick, this is probably the better option, althoough you should watch your repository closely before and after the `--continue` command.

Both commands will get you out of the cherry-pick state and allow you to perform the amend.

Answer (score 1):

The behaviour is defined in the [documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick).

What you need in your case is

> **--continue**
>    Continue the operation in progress using the information in 
>    .git/sequencer. Can be used to continue after resolving conflicts in a 
>    failed cherry-pick or revert.

Comment: I don't want a new commit but ammend to the last commit. This would create a new commit and would have to rebase then.

Comment: @garg10may Did you try using --no-commit with your cherrypick?

Answer (score 0):

When running actions like `cherry-pick`, `rebase` or `merge`, `git` keeps track of several info on the base commit.

It looks like a reasonable safety to prevent the base commit from being modified.

---

I would advise you to somehow finish your `cherry-pick`, and then use `rebase -i` to modifiy the sequence of commits you want.

If we use the following names :

```
--*--*-- ... --A--B <- HEAD
      \
       *-- ... X <- cherry-picked commit

# you are currently on B, you run :
git cherry-pick X
```

If you wish to reach :

```
--*--*-- ... --A--B'--X' <- cherry-picked version of X
      \           ^
       \          a modified version of B
        *-- ... X
```

you can :

```
# add the modifications intended for B' :
git add -p [files]
# create a regular commit, using "git commit" :
git commit

--*--*-- ... --A--B--C

# complete the cherry-pick process :
git add [files with solved conflicts]
git cherry-pick --continue

--*--*-- ... --A--B--C--X'

# use 'rebase -i A' to squash B and C into one commit
git rebase -i A
# set the rebase actions to "squash C into B"

# the result should be what you expect :
--*--*-- ... --A--B'--X'
```