# Xcode Version control: fatal: cannot do a partial commit during a merge?

Tags: xcode, git, version-control

When using git with Xcode interface, I get the following error after pressing **commit # Files and Push**.

**The working copy “Project” failed to commit files.**

> fatal: cannot do a partial commit during a merge.

I am using Xcode's Source Control. I have looked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5827944/git-error-on-commit-after-merge-fatal-cannot-do-a-partial-commit-during-a-mer) but have not found anything that resolves the issue for Xcode's Source Control.

Answer (score 1):

This issue is because of some issue with git head. Try using source tree application to do the commit and push to the git. It will work.

https://www.sourcetreeapp.com

Comment: does the above solution helped you?