# Xcode Version control: fatal: cannot do a partial commit during a merge

Tags: xcode, git, version-control

When using Xcode's Source Control, I get the following error after 
pressing **commit # Files and Push**.

**The working copy “Project” failed to commit files.**

> fatal: cannot do a partial commit during a merge.

I am using Xcode 9+. I have looked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5827944/git-error-on-commit-after-merge-fatal-cannot-do-a-partial-commit-during-a-mer) but have not found anything that resolves the issue for Xcode's Source Control.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: As the error says, there is a merge in progress. you can confirm this using git terminal / GUI in this directory.

Comment: So the only way to fix it would be to use the terminal?

Comment: No, definitely. Xcode 9 has a menu called `Source Control`. If you have set up this, it can `fetch & refresh` the code for you :)

Comment: ok so how do i fix this issue within xcode without using terminal

Comment: Have you tried `fetch & refresh` option in `Source Control` menu?

Comment: did it and it still go tthe same error message

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> *You will have to use your `terminal` to resolve this.* `Xcode` (as of Xcode 9) does not support many of the features in git e.g `git stash`.

**Option 1 - Stage changes and commit using `Xcode`**

Following [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5827944/git-error-on-commit-after-merge-fatal-cannot-do-a-partial-commit-during-a-mer), try to stage all the local changes and repeat your steps with Xcode

1. Open up `terminal`
2. Navigate to project directory: `cd /path/to/project`
3. Stage all local changes: `git add .`
4. Open Xcode and try to commit again.

---

**Option 2 - Stage and commit using `terminal`**

If `Option 1` did not resolve the issue, you can complete this task with `terminal` itself

1. Open up `terminal`
2. Navigate to project directory: `cd /path/to/project`
3. **Stash your changes (IMP)**: `git stash save name-this-stash`
4. Reset code changes: `git reset --hard HEAD~30`
5. Pull the latest state of remote: `git pull origin branch-name`
6. Re-apply local changes: `git stash apply`
7. Check current status: `git status`
8. Stage changes to commit: `git add file1 file2`
9. Commit changes: `git commit -m "commit-message"`
10. Push changes to remote: `git push origin branch-name`

Hope it helps!